# Not able to get datetime.time using datetime module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time

Below is the given code which uses datetime module.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time 
tup = (22,34,56)
dt_obj = datetime.time(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2])

print(time(dt_obj))
```

I need the output in format - datetime.time(22,34,56) but it is giving me below error.

> dt_obj = datetime.time(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2]) TypeError: descriptor
> 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

When I replace datetime.time with just time it gives me the time output but not the output format that I desire. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: to be precise with wording, `datetime.time(22,34,56)` is a data type (instance of class datetime.time), not a format. The string representation of that object has a format, namely HH:MM:SS, so when you use `print`, a string "22:34:56" is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `from datetime import time` so just use `time`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time 
tup = (22,34,56)
dt_obj = time(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2])
```

Now `dt_obj` is in the format that you desire:

```
 datetime.time(22, 34, 56)
```

Comment: Can also be simplified to `dt_obj = time(*tup)`

Comment: @BioGeek But my output with above code shows - 22:34:56

Comment: @isilia try `print(repr(dt_obj))` to the the object representation (instead of the object's string representation).

Comment: @MrFuppes - yes repr function does the job. But datetime.time as mentioned by BioGeek does not work and throws error "print(datetime.time(tup))
TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object"